# Greatest Common Divisor Giving 0 instead of 5

Tags: java

Calcing GCD doesn't give proper return

```
//CALC GCD
if (a != 0)
{
    b = b % a;

    result = gcd(b, a);

}
```

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Method names should start with lower case character.

Comment: I think you mean `result = GCD(rem, a);` when you call your method recursively.

Comment: You might wanna analyze your code again. You can start by [understanding recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion).

Comment: I think it should be like `int rem = a % b;`.

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring the result of the recursive call.

```
GCD(rem, a);
```

should be

```
result = GCD(rem, a);
```

Also note that your method assumes that the first argument is the smaller number. It will fail to produce the correct output if you call `GCD(15,10)` instead of `GCD(10,15)`. You can easily overcome this limitation if you add a condition to the start of the method which swaps `a` and `b` if `a > b`.